# Digital Input Voltage range selection

Tags: switches, opto-isolator, protection, tvs, digital-input

I am designing 24V industrial shields with 4 channel Digital Inputs. the digital inputs voltage range shall be set by 1P3T switch wherein the switch shall be actuated between 3 voltage ranges of 0-24V, 0-12V, 0-5V. For Eg: If[image] switch is set to 0-12V position, entire 4 DI terminals shall be rated for max 12V(or 24V or 5V) input signal, if sensor signal voltage greater than 12V applied the voltage has to be clamped. I'm attaching the circuit which I done for one voltage range for but im not able to do it for multiple voltage range and also for all channels.

As far as the reference I got from google is:
I can clamp maximum voltage by using either zener or TVS diode.
I also understood that by using DIP switch, we cannot achieve single range of voltage is passed to the circuit because if we forget to turn off other range, it may lead to short circuit, so finalised to have rotary switch.
The below attached image works with individual voltage range (simulated).

I hope my question is clear. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So... you're asking us to design this for you?  That's not how this site works.  What have you tried and how did it fail to meet your requirements?  Click the edit link below your question to add this info, otherwise the question will likely be closed.

Comment: Regarding the question, you didn't ask one that I can see.

Comment: Think voltage divider.....

Comment: For each of the three input voltage ranges, what is the threshold voltage range when you want the output to change state?  If all three input ranges can have the same transition voltage range, such as 1.8 V to 2.1 V, then the solution reduces to a single 1P3T switch plus 12 zener diodes.  This works only if all four inputs share a common ground as shown in your schematic.  If not, then hmmm . . .

Answer (score 0):

The LEDs at the inputs of the TLP292 [(datasheet here)](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/datasheet_en_20190520.pdf?did=15284) will decide their own voltage, which will be between 1.1V and 1.4V according to the datasheet. What you need to control is the current flowing in those LEDs, not the voltage across them.

Those zener diodes D7 to D10 are not helping at all. The datasheet tells us that there won't be more than 1.4V across the LEDs, never enough for the diodes to begin clamping anything.

First you must establish how much current needs to flow in an LED to get its corresponding transistor to turn fully on. With 10kΩ pull-up resistors to +3.3V, when the transistor is on, Ohm's law is used to calculate collector current \$I_C\$:

$$ I_C = \frac{3.3V}{10k\Omega} = 330\mu A $$

The datasheet gives a "current transfer ratio" (CTR) of as low as 50%. This implies that you need at least twice as much LED current \$I_F\$ as collector current:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_F &> \frac{I_C}{CTR} \\ \\
&> \frac{330\mu A}{50\%} \\ \\
&> 660\mu A
\end{aligned}
$$

To be safe, and to ensure you still have enough margin just in case you decide to reduce the collector pull-up resistances, perhaps aim for ten times that:

$$ I_F = 660\mu A \times 10 \approx 6mA $$

The maximum average LED current is \$50mA\$, so we aren't going to break anything.

Usually when we have a fixed voltage powering an LED, we control LED current with a resistor, in a setup like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYMqct.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here I've used a 5V source, which is shared between current limiting resistor \$R_1\$ and the LED. From the datasheet we learn that the LED requires at most 1.4V, which means the remaining \$5V - 1.4V = 3.6V\$ must be across \$R_1\$. By Ohm's law, we can calculate the value of \$R_1\$ required to pass 6mA of current:

$$ R_1 = \frac{V_{R1}}{I_F} = \frac{5.0V-1.4V}{6mA} = 600\Omega $$

While being correct for a voltage supply of 5V, this value for \$R_1\$ won't really work well for higher voltages. The LED voltage stays fixed, more or less, while the voltage across \$R_1\$ will rise with the supply. Therefore, with \$V_1 = 24V\$, current will rise to:

$$ I_F = \frac{V_1 - V_{LED}}{R_1} = \frac{24V - 1.4V}{600\Omega} = 38mA $$

That won't damage the LED, but it's very wasteful, and it will dissipate power in \$R_1\$:

$$ P_{R1} = I^2R = (38mA)^2 \times 600 = 870mW $$

That's enough to make \$R_1\$ quite hot.

Perhaps, then you could use a different resistor in each case, select one for 5v, another for 12V and yet another for 24V. Calculate the resistances require in each case:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_{1(5V)} &= 600\Omega \\ \\
R_{1(12V)} &= \frac{12V - 1.4V}{6mA} = 1.8k\Omega \\ \\
R_{1(24V)} &= \frac{24V - 1.4V}{6mA} = 3.9k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

You may find that the middle ground, \$R_1=1.8k\Omega\$, will work for all three cases. Let's calculate LED current \$I_F\$ for all three voltages, given this fixed value \$R_1 = 1.8k\Omega\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{F(5V)} &= \frac{5V - 1.4V}{1.8k\Omega} = 2mA \\ \\
I_{F(12V)} &= \frac{12V - 1.4V}{1.8k\Omega} = 6mA \\ \\
I_{F(24V)} &= \frac{24V - 1.4V}{1.8k\Omega} = 13mA \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

All those values are respectable. The lowest current 2mA is still easily sufficient to produce the required \$330\mu A\$ of collector current, and the highest 13mA through \$R_1\$ would dissipate only 300mW.

It should be clear by now that having three different "operating voltages" is not necessary. At the very most, you need only two different regimes. Let's say we divide operation into two ranges, one where the input is between 5V and 12V, and the other for 12V to 24V operation.

If we decide that we want 6mA to flow when the input is at the *top* of each range, then we have these two values for \$R_1\$, that we calculated above:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_{1(12V)} &= \frac{12V - 1.4V}{6mA} = 1.8k\Omega \\ \\
R_{1(24V)} &= \frac{24V - 1.4V}{6mA} = 3.9k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now find what current would flow with inputs at the lower end of those ranges, using the appropriate range resistance:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{F(5V)} &= \frac{5V - 1.4V}{1.8k\Omega} = 2mA \\ \\
I_{F(12V)} &= \frac{12V - 1.4V}{3.9k\Omega} = 2.7mA \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Both of those are still sufficient to saturate the output transistor. It remains to devise a scheme to select the range, using a single switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTsiU1.png)</sup>

With switch SW1 closed, which short-circuits \$R_2\$, the total resistance in the LED current loop is only \$R_1 = 1.8k\Omega\$. When SW1 is open, the total resistance rises to \$R_1 + R_2 = 3.9k\Omega\$.

---

User AnalogKid pointed out that I didn't answer your question, which was to employ a single switch to control the operating voltage for all four channels simultaneously. That's my bad, I didn't read carefully enough.

However, in keeping with the idea that you may not even need to switch between regimes, there is a solution using JFETs that would keep current at 6mA or so regardless of input voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTY2wQ.png)</sup>

As current rises through J1 and R1, the voltage across R1 increases to the point where it begins switching *off* J1, preventing further current increase. To limit current to 6mA, from the datasheet find the \$V_{GS}\$ required to pass 6mA of channel current, and choose \$R_1\$ according to:

$$ R_1 = \frac{V_{GS(6mA)}}{6mA} $$

This only works for current in one direction (to the right through J1). If the input becomes negative, causing current to flow in the other direction, current would be almost unrestricted, so D1 is there to prevent that.

Comment: I don't see how that circuit will work with a single 1P3T switch for all four inputs.

Comment: @AnalogKid Neither do I. I failed to see that requirement in the question Sigh.

Comment: Nice to know I'm not completely losing it.  You, on the other hand . . .

Comment: @AnalogKid I, on the other hand, have lost it. It's gone, whatever sliver of sanity I had left.

Comment: Sign on the wall of a metals recycling plant unloading zone:  Never apologize for something that made you smile.